# Stack offset of 4376 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 280 bytes, please minimize large stack variables

Tags: anchor, pda

```
Error: Function _ZN137_$LT$solana_randomness_consumer..InitiateWheel$u20$as$u20$anchor_lang..Accounts$LT$solana_randomness_consumer..InitiateWheelBumps$GT$$GT$12try_accounts17h8805a14f72c43977E Stack offset of 4376 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 280 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
```

I keep getting this error, and my calls to the smart contract fail because of it. I boxed every single possible account in the account, I try boxing other structs but it doesn't affect it at all.

I am not quite sure what I can do here to be honest. Since if I edit other structs it doesn't affect the amount of bytes that is exceeded. Only InitiateWheel matters.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to add `#[inline(never)] to any functions that` InitiateWheel` might call into.

For example, the spl-stake-pool program was having issues in its main processor function because the compiler was inlining everything, causing the stack to be too big, so we added that directive to some functions, ie https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/4f1668510adef2117ee3c043bd26b79789e67c8d/stake-pool/program/src/processor.rs#L712